# Autocomplete with django Haystack Solr Error

Tags: django, solr, autocomplete, django-haystack

I'm stuck in the following problem: When I try to implement Autocomplete following the example in this [link](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html), modifying search_index.py as follows:

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from myapp.models import Note


class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')
    # We add this for autocomplete.
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='content')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Note.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I get the following error:

Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: Error 400 ERROR: [doc=example.autor.1] unknown field 'content_auto'].

Of course, "content_auto" is not and attribute of the class autor, but accordingly to the Autocomplete documentation, that's needed.

Comment: Did you update the schema.xml and restart your solr server?

Comment: @21Zoo I face the same problem. What is the update needed in schema.xml?